# For a given query I am having same results with some key varying in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

So I used this aggregate query.

`db.aggregate([{'$group':{'compound':'xyz','target.id':'123'}}])`

In the above example for compound xyz am getting 12 results having target.id as 123. so I would like to group them by using above aggregate query but it throws this error.

`Failed to execute script.
Error:
Assert: command failed: {
    "code" : 40234,
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "The field 'compound' must be an accumulator object"
} : aggregate failed`

Comment: What is your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to pass `_id` as the first field while use `$group`.

> The `_id` field is mandatory; however, you can specify a `_id` value of null to calculate accumulated values for all the input documents as a whole.

And check [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) how to use `$group`.

Comment: Hardik, How can I sort after performing aggregate? It says sort operation cannnot be performed on aggregate.

Comment: @shanmukavinash, paste here your DB data, whole aggregation query and expected output. So, I can help you accurately.